# Pass value from OnClick JavaScript Detail Page Button to a Controller

Tags: javascript, button

Good morning. 
Is there a way to pass a value from an OnClick Javascript Detail Page Button to a Controller *other than the controller that the button is on*?

This is my JavaScript:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/26.0/apex.js")}

var engID=window.sfdcPage.entityId
var postType="statement of work";   

window.location="https://rsidemo1-dev-ed--c.na24.visual.force.com/apex/VfFilePost?scontrolCaching=1&id="+engID;
```

I want to assign postType to a variable in the controller of the VfFilePost Page. I am new to Salesforce and programming. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass it as an encoded URL parameter:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/26.0/apex.js")}

var engID=window.sfdcPage.entityId
var postType="statement of work";   

window.location="https://rsidemo1-dev-ed--c.na24.visual.force.com/apex/VfFilePost?scontrolCaching=1&id="+engID+"&postType="+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(postType, 'UTF-8');
```

And then retrieve and decode it in your recipient controller:

```
String rawPostType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('postType');
String postType = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(rawPostType, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: I'm getting an error. EncodingUtil is not defined. Do I have the correct requirescript notation?

Comment: The second excerpt is for an Apex controller.  Were you not talking about Apex controllers?  What type of controller did you mean?

Comment: The Apex controller extension for the VfFilePost Page.

Comment: You should be able to run the second excerpt within the controller extension.  `EncodingUtil` is a standard Apex library.

Comment: Were you able to get it working in the end?

Comment: just got it working.

Comment: window.location="https://rsidemo1-dev-ed--c.na24.visual.force.com/apex/VfFilePost?scontrolCaching=1&id="+engID+"&postType="+postType;

Comment: Had to remove EncodingUtil.urlEncode(postType, 'UTF-8') and just pass the string, but it works. Any reason why it would be a bad idea to remove this?

Comment: Great, well done.  It shouldn't really be an issue unless you're passing weird symbols back and forth.  Just be careful if you're using the string in SOQL queries - see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
VF Page - Action function<br><apex:actionFunction name="sendpostType" action="{!sendpostType}" rerender="pb">
<apex:param name="x" value="" assignTo="{!postTypeValue}" />
```

javascript code:

```
      sendpostType(postType);
```

controller code:

public class TestController{
public string postTypeValue{get;set;}
public TestController(){
postTypeValue = '';
}
public void sendpostType(){
system.debug('postTypeValue' + postTypeValue);
}
}